Decomposition of symmetric powers of the fundamental representation of $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$
Let $(k,0,...,0)$ denote the highest weights vector of an irreducible representation of $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$. I read in Fulton-Harris, that this representation may be obtained as a direct summand of $\text{Sym}^kV$, where $V$ is the fundamental representation of $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$.
Is there a simple way to describe $(k,0,...,0)$ (as a subrepresentation of $\text{Sym}^kV$) as the kernel of some explicit map ($\text{Sym}^kV\longrightarrow *$)? I read that the $(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)$ representations could be constructed from the $k$'th alternating product of $V$ using the contraction maps associated to the symplectic form. I am particularly interested to know if there are known constructions of an infinite, symplectic family of irreducible representations of $\text{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ (direct summands of $V^{\otimes k}$ for $k$ odd), which project as a vector space to $\text{Sym}^{k'}V$ for some arbitrarily large $k' < k$.
A reference would also be appreciated.

For completeness of MathOverflow, compare with: this answer which is about the alternating powers of the same standard (=first fundamental) representation $V$.

Yes, it is just $\operatorname{Sym}^k(V)$ itself.
Specifically: Let $V = \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ be the natural module for $Sp(2n, \mathbb{C})$. Then for all $k \geq 1$, the symmetric power $\operatorname{Sym}^k(V)$ is an irreducible $Sp(2n,\mathbb{C})$-module of highest weight $(k,0,\ldots,0) = k \varpi_1$.
See for example §24.2, p. 406 in Fulton-Harris.
Some alternative references, which are also relevant when you look at the same question for $Sp(2n,K)$ with $K$ an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic.

II.2.17 in: Jantzen, Jens Carsten Representations of algebraic groups. Second edition. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, 107. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2003. xiv+576 pp. ISBN: 0-8218-3527-0.
8.1(c) in: Seitz, Gary M. The maximal subgroups of classical algebraic groups. Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 67 (1987), no. 365, iv+286 pp.
Suprunenko, I. D. Conditions for the irreducibility of the restrictions of irreducible representations of the group SL(n,K) to connected algebraic subgroups. Dokl. Akad. Nauk BSSR 30 (1986), no. 3, 204-207, 284.


What about $k>n$?

@kindasorta: Sorry, that was a mistake - it holds for all $k \geq 1$.

As testaccount says, it is just $\mathrm{Sym}^k(V)$. One way to see it is the Weyl dimension formula. The positive roots of type $C_n$ are $\{2\epsilon_i:1\le i\le n\}\cup\{\epsilon_i\pm\epsilon_j:1\le i<j\le n\}$. Weyl dimension formula tells us
$$\dim(V_{k\epsilon_1})=\prod_{\alpha\in\Delta_+}\frac{(k\epsilon_1+\rho,\alpha)}{(\rho,\alpha)},$$
but the only $\alpha\in\Delta_+$ that contribute to the product are those with nontrivial $\epsilon_1$-component, i.e., $\{2\epsilon_1\}\cup\{\epsilon_1\pm\epsilon_j:1<j\le n\}$.
Now noting that $\rho=n\epsilon_1+\cdots+\epsilon_n$,
$$\begin{align*}
\dim(V_{k\epsilon_1})&=\frac{(k\epsilon_1+\rho,2\epsilon_1)}{(\rho,2\epsilon_1)}\prod_{j=2}^n\frac{(k\epsilon_1+\rho,\epsilon_1+\epsilon_j)}{(\rho,\epsilon_1+\epsilon_j)}\cdot\prod_{j=2}^n\frac{(k\epsilon_1+\rho,\epsilon_1-\epsilon_j)}{(\rho,\epsilon_1-\epsilon_j)}\\
&=\frac{n+k}n\prod_{j=2}^n\frac{2n+k+1-j}{2n+1-j}\cdot\prod_{j=2}^n\frac{j+k-1}{j-1}\\
&=\frac{(k+1)\cdots(2n+k-1)}{1\cdots (2n-1)}\\
&={2n+k-1\choose k}.
\end{align*}$$
But this is just the dimension of $\mathrm{Sym}^k(V)$ so the natural inclusion $V_{k\epsilon_1}\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Sym}^k(V)$ is an isomorphism!
